# Extend Windows process memory limit

Tags: windows, memory, memory-management

I'm new to stackoverflow and C/C++.

While experimenting programming in windows I noticed that there's a certain limit on how much memory a process can allocate and I wonder how to extend it.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Try compiling for 64-bit.  Also to help us help you add some numbers to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options:

**This is for x86 windows:** A 32-Bit process has a limit of 2GB of memory. But this can be increased to 3GB by booting the system with the BCD flag `/INCREASEUSERVA 3072`. This has some quirks though. On a 32-bit system, the 4GB of memory is split, 2GB for User mode, and 2GB for Kernel mode. Now, it's 3GB for user mode and 1GB for kernel mode. This is fine, but sometimes kernel drivers need more heap space than required, filling up that 1GB for kernel mode.

You can also use Address Windowing Extensions. This allows you to use physical memory greater than 4GB while still using 32-bit addresses. This can be a good option if you want to keep your process 32-bit.

Lastly, just compile your program as 64-bit. You remove the user-mode address mode restriction of addresses, less overhead because of no x86 virtual CPU, and you get enhanced security mitigations too.

Answer (score 0):

for knowing how much memory is available.that really depends on the environment you are using: what OS are you running code in, is that a 16 or 32 or 64-bit memory architecture?

For example, if you are running code on Windows 10 you can use the GlobalMemoryStatusEx() facility [GlobalMemoryStatusEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-globalmemorystatusex?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

functions like `malloc` which can allocate memory for you,they can also fail.in that case they will return `nullpoiter` without allocating even a byte ,otherwise it will allocate memory requested.it will allocate all memory requested or failing without allocating at all.

,but also there is limit on memory, you can use.

for example Windows 7 64-bit will only let you access 8 GB for your program(which is most likely enough)even if you have a lot more memory free.

also check this [getrlimit, setrlimit - control maximum resource consumption](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setrlimit.html)